# Flush cached selector in Adobe Experience Manager without flushing entire directory

Tags: apache, cache

How can I use selector based cache flushing in Adobe Experience Manager?

- `http://example.com/content/myapp/us/en.child1.xml`
- `http://example.com/content/myapp/us/en.child2.xml`

Lets say,we have xml's cached under the folder as

```
/<docroot-cache>/content/myapp/us/
->en.child1.xml
->en.child2.xml
->en.child99.xml
->en.child100.xml
->en.html
->en.model.json
```

I need to provide selector based caching, that is to flush `en.child1.xml` only and should not flush `en.child2.xml` when the request for flush happens for `/content/myapp/us/en.child1.xml`
I've tried dispatcher flush invalidation through HTTP call like:

```
GET http://mydispatcher/dispatcher/invalidate.cache
**Headers**
CQ-Action Activate
CQ-Handle /content/myapp/us/en.child1.xml
Content-Type Application/xml
```

But,all files under `us` folder(i.e. all selector for `en` page) get invalidated.  How can I invalidate just `en.child1.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Just posting the answer if it can be useful for anyone else, after some research, I got this working with CQ-Action Delete.

Comment: Can you add any details?  How is this feature used?   Can you link to the documentation?